# Как передавать в метод массив фиксированной длины?

Tags: java

Как передавать в метод массив фиксированной длины?

```
class A {
   final int length;

   void foo(Object[length] objects) {} // ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Можно только все значения массива сделать отдельными параметрами метода:

```
void foo(Object first, Object second, Object third) { }
```

Также можно использовать проверку длины массива с пробросом исключения в теле метода:

```
void foo(Object[] objects)
{
    if (objects.length != length)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect array size");
    }
    ...
}
```

Но это уже проверка, а не ограничение.